# access #ifdef code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

if the code is :

```
#ifdef ABC

code();

#endif
```

I want to access the function code() using Open Declaration. How can I do this without defining ABC in source code..

Comment: Are you using the Eclipse C Development Tools? (CDT) If so, please say so in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Eclipse to index code inside #ifdef .... #endif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121920/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-index-code-inside-ifdef-endif)

Answer (score 2):

Actually for me, this worked.. Have a lot of weird make files throughout the project..

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols -> Symbols Tab -> Add...

Turn off Show built-in-values to avoid confusion. 
Make sure your correct build Configuration is set above.

Hit Apply...

You will know it worked if it asks to rebuild the Index.

Indigo (3.7)

Answer (score 1):

Go into "Project/Properties…" to open the configuration for your project.

After that, go into "C/C++ Build", then "Build Variables". Then add an "ABC" variable.