# Eclipse CDT editor doesn't recognize OpenGL extensions

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, eclipse-cdt, glew

I'm using Vertex Array Objects and Vertex Buffer Objects in Eclipse, but the editor doesn't appear to recognize the function declarations. The program compiles and executes without any complaint.

[image: screenshot]

(Note that the errors are "Function could not be resolved.")

I've tried using both GLee and GLEW, but the results are the same. Any ideas on how to get Eclipse to recognize the functions in the editor?

Comment: Those aren't extension functions. They're *core* OpenGL functions.

Comment: Please don't post bitmaps.  Post the code itself.

Comment: For me YRH's answer to [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420336/eclipse-marks-opengl-functions-cannot-be-resolved) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general, OpenGL function pointers like this have to be defined by macros that resolve to some function name. That plays havoc with IDEs and their attempts to figure out what is going on.

Ultimately, if your IDE can't handle it, you'll just have to find a way to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is anything special about OpenGl Extensions but I do know in general I often have to dig down to the root folder that contains the .h files for my library and explicitly add all the folders to my include paths. Adding the topmost parent doesn't cut it for the editor. Once I add them all I then rebuild the indices (usually to get type-ahead features working). It's strange that the editor is more picky about this than the compiler but I have seen it happen with multiple libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, and the only thing that fixed it was to start a brand new C++ project, make the **very first** include `#include <GL/glew.h>`, and copy in the rest of the code.  If the project is set up without glew.h as the first import, it never reconfigures itself for some reason.

I tried manually messing with the project and global properties in Eclipse; nothing worked except the above.

RE: Nicol Bolas's answer, it's true that Eclipse cannot parse the macros well enough to generate all the tooltips and autocompletes, but it will recognize the functions and enforce correct arguments.

Just make sure you have the most up-to-date version of Eclipse CDT (and GLEW).

Answer (score 0):

In some occasions it might work when you rebuild the index (right-click project > Index > Rebuild)